# How to add efficient cross-platform support for my C# DLL

Tags: c#, dll, cross-platform

I have developed a small C# DLL, that acts as a connector to my larger C# service application. The connector DLL simply embeds the TCP-based protocols required by my service application, and exposes communication methods and evnts to user .Net applications so that they can interact with the service. Everything works as expected.

Now my goal is to add support for user applications in other languages/platforms (Win/*nix) to interact with my service. Since my service interacts using TCP, I trust that the simplest way to achieve this goal is to replicate my connector code in a couple of other languages (say C, C++, Java).

My questions are:

1. Are there any efficient tools that help to do this kind of
   replication (code-converters are no good)?
2. Or, are there any better ways to achieve this goal?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you thought on converting the DLL to .NET Core? That way it will work on Windows, Linux (most common distributions at least) and macOs

Comment: You shouldn't try to deal with other languages; if a language want to use another language, it's not your role to accommodate it. Moreover, it's a PITA. So yeah, either you replicate in the other languages you want to support, or you use a cross-platform API. So as @CamiloTerevinto says, .NET Core. About code conversion, I suggest you never count on it. Unless your code is ridiculously simple, it won't end well.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Wasn't aware of that. Thanks for mentioning it. Shall google for it.

Comment: I'm on VS 2008, so at the moment .Net Core is not doable.

Comment: Why not? Do you have a requirement that prevents you from going to VS2017? That would be the only simple, very low effort solution. VS2008 is extremely old already, by the way

Comment: Only thing stopping me from upgrading is $$$. :D This is my personal project (hence cannot use office resources), and I'm pretty much broke.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more search, I am accepting the comment by @CamiloTerevinto as the answer. Either I could upgrade to VS2017 and try out his suggestion, or I could find developers in other languages to rewrite my connector. Looks like there is no third option.